# adding textChangedListener to TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext, addtextchangedlistener

I want to add `textChangedListener()` on `TextInputEditText`. But can't find any of those listeners.

Like `editext.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()...)`, is that method available for `TextInputEditText`?
If no such listener is available then how to fetch string from `TextInputEditText`, while user is writing in it?

Comment: we are getting `addTextChangedListener` on **TextInputEditText**

Answer (score 0):

First, find the `TextInputEditText` from its id.

```
TextInputEditTexteditText = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
```

And then you can add `addTextChangeListener` in following way

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        inputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(editable.length()>0);
                    }
        });
```

You can refer [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText&method=addTextChangedListener), Hope this will help.

Comment: i know how to use text change listener in case of EditText...  I was trying to find textChangedListener for TextInputEditText...   the above llistener is not working for TextInputEditText but it is working for EditText

Comment: Hey, @shubhamprakash I have updated my answer please check now.